# Setup wordpress site from live to local, URLs are not working

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, xampp, relative-path, absolute-path

3/26: I created the Wordpress website on a live server. I downloaded a copy to my XAMPP server. I exported the database and created a local one. I modified the wp-config.php file to connect to it. That all works. However, I am not able to use any of the links in the navbar and otherwise to open any of the pages and posts. All those hyperlinks have absolute addresses that use the domain name of the live server. I can add the directory path and go to "/index.php" under localhost but all the other paths are open ended with no file name and they do not work. If I do not use "index.php" and just have a "/" it will not go to the home page. For the home page, if I leave out the "index.php" file name, it will have the header and navbar and say "Oops! That page can’t be found." If I use open ended links to anything else, it will say "Error establishing a database connection."

3/27: Thank you all very much for your responses! I have a plugin installed that I have not used yet called "Velvet Blues Update URLs." I will give that a try. I also have "All-in-One WP Migration" and "Duplicator," but the website is over 600mb in size so the free versions of those will not work.

Comment: Make sure you rewrite is enabled and from admin side once set permalink

Comment: fix your `.htaccess` file with resaving the Permalink structure. Also,just importing the db is not make sense. You should find and replace all urls from db. like `www.live-site.com` need to be converted as `www.development-site.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving WP from local to live server has always been a headache. For this here is a plugin I often use and never encounter any issue again. https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

You should use it to migrate your website. By the way what you can if you dont what to use that plugin is to find replace in the DB file all URLs before moving to Live Server DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use temporary URL in your local install by editing wp-config.php and defining  `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` e.g.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: In theory these steps should be sufficient, but WordPress and its plugins stores hardcoded URLs in database. I always have to edit SQL when migrating site between domains. You can read more at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have cloned the database in your local install as well. If that's the case, you have to update all the entries in the db to match the url of your local install.

If the live site was called http://example.com you should find every occurrence of it and change it to http://localhost/my_install.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost/my_install') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost/my_install');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost/my_install');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost/my_install');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://example.com', 'src="http://localhost/my_install');

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `guid` =  REPLACE( `guid` , 'http://example.com' , 'http://localhost/my_install' ) WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment';

UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost/my_install') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

This SQL queries should do that for you. Just replace the dummy data with your actual one. And resave the Permalink structure(Settings -> Permalinks).